# How to download excel from SharePoint site using VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, sharepoint

I want to download a excel file from a SharePoint site.

The URL that I get using share option is:

```
Dim myURL As String
myURL = "https://xxxxxxx.sharepoint.com/:x:/r/sites/Engineering_tools/Automation_Master.xlsm?d=webeecea430dc4311b99ccefc1a1faf08&csf=1&web=1&e=ETgkgf"

Dim fileLocation As String
fileLocation = "C:\temp\UI_Ouput\CWE_Design_Automation\HBU3_Automation_Master.xlsm"
```

I have tried the following methods to download:

1. `My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile(myURL, fileName, "user@abc.com", "password")`

Result 1: 0 KB file created

2.

```
Imports System.Net
   
Dim webClient As New WebClient
webClient.DownloadFile(myURL, fileName)
```

Result 2: The remote server returned an error: (403)Forbidden.

Now, I don't understand if the issue is with the URL link or with the code.

Comment: Maybe have a look at the SharePoint client library https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-client-library-code#basic-operations-with-the-sharepoint-net-client-object-model

Comment: You need to authenticate before you can download from sharepoint.

Comment: You are receiving blank data because the link has one or more redirects that are not being followed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use code similar to this which will authenticate you.

```
' Get NugetPackage Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM

Imports System.Net
Imports System.Security
Imports Microsoft.SharePoint.Client

Private Const Username As String = "username@tenant.onmicrosoft.com"
Private Const Password As String = "password"
Private Const Url As String = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/"
Private SecurePassword = New SecureString()

Private Sub ExampleUsage()
    For Each c In Password.ToCharArray()
        SecurePassword.AppendChar(c)
    Next
    Dim Credentials = New SharePointOnlineCredentials(Username, SecurePassword)
    DownloadFile(Url, Credentials, "/Shared Documents/Report.xslx")
End Sub

Private Shared Sub DownloadFile(ByVal webUrl As String, ByVal credentials As ICredentials, ByVal fileRelativeUrl As String)
    Using client = New WebClient()
        client.Credentials = credentials
        client.Headers.Add("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f")
        client.DownloadFile(webUrl, fileRelativeUrl)
    End Using
End Sub
```